# How to parse confluent avro kafka messages in spark when the latest schema in schema registry is missing some fields

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, avro, confluent-schema-registry

I am reading and de serializing the messages from Kafka in spark streaming using abris

`from_confluent_avro( za.co.absa.abris.avro.functions.from_confluent_avro)` by passing the schema registry configuration, the problem is there are some scenarios when the latest schema in schema registry is missing some fields and since we use latest schema while DE serializing the messages it is making the missing fields null where as the Kafka message has value for those fields.

abris configuration :

```
SchemaManager.PARAM_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_TOPIC -> topicNm,
        SchemaManager.PARAM_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL -> schemaRegUrl,
        SchemaManager.PARAM_VALUE_SCHEMA_NAMING_STRATEGY -> "topic.name",
        SchemaManager.PARAM_VALUE_SCHEMA_ID -> "latest")
```

Schema

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "topic_test",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "actions",
      "type": [
        "null",
        "int"
      ],
      "default": null
    },
    {
      "name": "clicks",
      "type": [
        "null",
        "int"
      ],
      "default": null
    },
    {
      "name": "deal_id",
      "type": [
        "null",
        "string"
      ],
      "default": null
    },
    {
      "name": "deal_line_id",
      "type": [
        "null",
        "string"
      ],
      "default": null
    },
    {
      "name": "delivery_date",
      "type": [
        "null",
        "long"
      ],
      "default": null
    },
    {
      "name": "delivery_source",
      "type": [
        "null",
        "string"
      ],
      "default": null
    },
    {
      "name": "delivery_type",
      "type": [
        "null",
        "string"
      ],
      "default": null
    },
    {
      "name": "external_ps_ad_id",
      "type": [
        "null",
        "string"
      ],
      "default": null
    },
    {
      "name": "external_ps_ad_name",
      "type": [
        "null",
        "string"
      ],
      "default": null
    },
    {
      "name": "gross_revenue",
      "type": [
        "null",
        "int"
      ],
      "default": null
    },
    {
      "name": "index",
      "type": [
        "null",
        "string"
      ],
      "default": null
    },
    {
      "name": "job_id",
      "type": [
        "null",
        "string"
      ],
      "default": null
    },
    {
      "name": "metric2",
      "type": [
        "null",
        "int"
      ],
      "default": null
    },
    {
      "name": "metric3",
      "type": [
        "null",
        "int"
      ],
      "default": null
    },
    {
      "name": "net_revenue",
      "type": [
        "null",
        "int"
      ],
      "default": null
    },
    {
      "name": "order_id",
      "type": [
        "null",
        "string"
      ],
      "default": null
    },
    {
      "name": "order_line_item_id",
      "type": [
        "null",
        "string"
      ],
      "default": null
    },
    {
      "name": "parent_deal_line_id",
      "type": [
        "null",
        "string"
      ],
      "default": null
    },
    {
      "name": "production_system_id",
      "type": [
        "null",
        "string"
      ],
      "default": null
    },
    {
      "name": "source",
      "type": {
        "type": "record",
        "name": "source",
        "fields": [
          {
            "name": "destinationTenantName",
            "type": [
              "null",
              "string"
            ],
            "default": null
          },
          {
            "name": "endOfJob",
            "type": [
              "null",
              "boolean"
            ],
            "default": null
          },
          {
            "name": "entityType",
            "type": [
              "null",
              "string"
            ],
            "default": null
          },
          {
            "name": "externalSystemName",
            "type": [
              "null",
              "string"
            ],
            "default": null
          },
          {
            "name": "jobid",
            "type": [
              "null",
              "string"
            ],
            "default": null
          },
          {
            "name": "parentJobId",
            "type": [
              "null",
              "string"
            ],
            "default": null
          },
          {
            "name": "recordKey",
            "type": [
              "null",
              "string"
            ],
            "default": null
          },
          {
            "name": "sourceSystemName",
            "type": [
              "null",
              "string"
            ],
            "default": null
          },
          {
            "name": "sourceTenantName",
            "type": [
              "null",
              "string"
            ],
            "default": null
          },
          {
            "name": "tenant_name",
            "type": [
              "null",
              "string"
            ],
            "default": null
          },
          {
            "name": "topicPrefix",
            "type": [
              "null",
              "string"
            ],
            "default": null
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "write_identifier",
      "type": [
        "null",
        "string"
      ],
      "default": null
    }
  ]
}
```

message in kafka :

```
    {
      "actions" : 200,
      "clicks" : 100,
      "deal_id" : "6362359ce058c0124d04e14d",
      "deal_line_id" : "636235b0e058c0124d04e16e",
      "delivery_date" : 1667606400000,
      "delivery_source" : "s4jY-JDRS8atYVX6VrvaqA",
      "delivery_type" : "test primary",
      "external_ps_ad_id" : "6147090412",
      "external_ps_ad_name" : "ank_deal_1234",
      "gross_revenue" : 0,
      "impressions" : 8000,
      "index" : "",
      "job_id" : "e5d66396-b9e5-4662-a574-a342d517566a",
      "metric1" : 8000,
      "metric2" : 100,
      "metric3" : 200,
      "net_revenue" : 0,
      "order_id" : "test order",
      "order_line_item_id" : "test olid",
      "parent_deal_line_id" : "",
      "production_system_id" : "test production_system_id",
      "source" : {
        "destinationTenantName" : "testtenant",
        "endOfJob" : false,
        "entityType" : "testenitty",
        "externalSystemName" : "server",
        "jobid" : "d357c9d5-c004-4555-a581-864ab2f2ebfb",
        "parentJobId" : "e5d66396-b9e5-4662-a574-a342d517566a",
        "recordKey" : "6147090412_6McFTGZvQxuwJxAwUFRmmA_2022-11-05_s4jY-JDRS8atYVX6VrvaqA",
        "sourceSystemName" : "test",
        "sourceTenantName" : "test",
        "tenant_name" : "test",
        "topicPrefix" : "test"
      },
      "write_identifier" : ""
    }
```

To de-serialize using a static avro schema file I tried below:

```
 val jsonFormatSchema = new String(
                      Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("C:\\Users\\leo_t" +
                        "\\src\\main\\resources\\ddavro.avsc")))

                    val deserDF = result.select(za.co.absa.abris.avro.functions.from_avro(col("value"),
                      jsonFormatSchema).as("convertedMsg"))
                      .select("convertedMsg.*")
                    deserDF .show(10,false)
```

Getting below error message:

```
2022-11-07 11:13:05,355  [ERROR] org.apache.spark.executor.Executor - Exception in task 0.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 14)
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Malformed records are detected in record parsing.
    at za.co.absa.abris.avro.sql.AvroDataToCatalyst.nullSafeEval(AvroDataToCatalyst.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.serializefromobject_doConsume_0$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$11$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:619)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:255)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:247)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:836)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:836)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:402)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:408)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 12
    at org.apache.avro.io.parsing.Symbol$Alternative.getSymbol(Symbol.java:460)
    at org.apache.avro.io.ResolvingDecoder.readIndex(ResolvingDecoder.java:284)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readWithoutConversion(GenericDatumReader.java:187)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:160)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readField(GenericDatumReader.java:259)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readRecord(GenericDatumReader.java:247)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readWithoutConversion(GenericDatumReader.java:179)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:160)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:153)
    at za.co.absa.abris.avro.sql.AvroDataToCatalyst.decodeVanillaAvro(AvroDataToCatalyst.scala:137)
    at za.co.absa.abris.avro.sql.AvroDataToCatalyst.decode(AvroDataToCatalyst.scala:103)
    at za.co.absa.abris.avro.sql.AvroDataToCatalyst.nullSafeEval(AvroDataToCatalyst.scala:59)
    ... 22 more
2022-11-07 11:13:05,407  [ERROR] org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager - Task 0 in stage 3.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
```

Comment: Can you create a [mcve]? Otherwise, what fields are you referring to? Avro always projects into the **reader schema**. So, if the latest schema doesn't have fields that do exist in the record, then those will not still exist in your output dataframe.

Comment: Reading all these columns:
actions,clicks,deal_id,deal_line_id,delivery_date,delivery_source,delivery_type,external_ps_ad_id,external_ps_ad_name,gross_revenue,impressions,index,job_id,metric1,metric2,metric3,net_revenue,order_id,order_line_item_id,parent_deal_line_id,production_system_id
but if you notice schema doesn't have impressions filed in it and hence while de-serializing I am not able to fetch the value of it.

Comment: Is it not a  common scenarios when latest schema missing some fields and while de-serializing in spark with latest schema we miss fields in o/p DF ? Either we have to read message by message and read first 4 magic bytes to get the schema Id and then pass this schema registry to download the relevant schema and then deser. This entire process will be time consuming , there must be some other easy way that I am missing.

Comment: It's not time consuming. The schema is cached after the first request. And right. Your schema will always decide what fields are in your dataframe, as mentioned.

Comment: Ok. 
If I know the complete set of column that are possible to come in any message, can I pass the avro schema from a file and use that to deserialize the message, instead of decoding the schemaId from message and use it to download the releveant schema?

Comment: added code snippet  to de-ser by passing the super set schema.

Comment: You can use a schema file, **but** Spark is meant to run distributed, so putting an absolute path to your local Windows filesystem shouldn't be used when you actually "deploy" the code elsewhere. 2) You could just use an earlier ID, not the "latest" 3) If you want to use your own schema, you still need to remove the schemaId from the actual bytes of the record. Refer https://www.confluent.io/blog/consume-avro-data-from-kafka-topics-and-secured-schema-registry-with-databricks-confluent-cloud-on-azure/

Comment: 1) Added absolute path to run from local.
2) I could but there is no guarantee that latest-1 (an earlier ) schema has all the fields.
3) I meant to say If I can pass the schema from a file (copy of what we have in schema registry + the missing fields), I am getting array index out of bound, because message has schemaId in it, or am not doing it in a right way?

Comment: Like I said, you need to remove that ID. The linked blog post shows the functions to do what using substring commands - `fn.expr("substring(value, 6, length(value)-5)"))`

Comment: I have followed  [link](https://www.confluent.io/blog/consume-avro-data-from-kafka-topics-and-secured-schema-registry-with-databricks-confluent-cloud-on-azure/)

Steps that I have performed:
fetch the schemaid from each msg
download the schema 
now the challenge I am facing is:
Say I am reading 1000 offsets at a time and in these 1000 offsets I got two distinct schemas, now how can I pass the relevant schema to from_avro function. Do I need to loop based on the schema Id and perform rest of the operation? I believe thats what done in the shared link, but I dont want to run my job in loop

Comment: You can either use SparkSQL to group by the ID or you can skip the ID and provide your own reader schema that has all the fields you want to extract. Either way, you still need a loop to process all records, eventually

Comment: Looks like, providing a superset schema of all the fields won't work as order of the fields in kafka message is not same. @OneCricketeer am I doing it right? Does the order of the fields matters in schema?

Comment: Order doesn't matter for Avro. Fields are mapped by name